# HTML email, tables and content are cropped/collapsed on themselves(Outlook)

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am working on an HTML email for work. I haven't done this in 10+ years and for the life of me, after reading up and re-learning the "how" of html emails(sorta), I cant figure out why my HTML tables are collapsing in on themselves.

I've checked on different devices and desktop apps and so far so good EXCEPT Outlook.

On outlook, my email shows up squished. it shows up like this

[image]

Here is a part of the email.
(I removed some stuff because of work privacy stuff but its essentially all there)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>TITLE HERE</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    
    <style type="text/css">
    
        table td {border: 0px solid #DDDDDD;} 
    
        .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; background-color: #F1F1F1; }
        .ExternalClass { width: 100%; background-color: #F1F1F1; }
        body { width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-family: Arial, Times, serif }
        *[class*="mobileOn"] { display: none !important; max-height: none !important; }
        
        @-ms-viewport{ width: device-width; }




        .smdWidth{width:600px;}
        .smdPadding{padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;}

        @media only screen and (max-width: 639px){
            .wrapper{ width:100%;  padding: 0 !important; }
        }    


        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){ 
            p{padding:10px;}
            .wrapper, .smdWidth{ width:320px;  padding: 0 !important; } 
            .centerClass{ margin:0 auto !important; } 
            .imgClass{width:100% !important; height:auto;}        
            .container{ width:300px;  padding: 0 !important; }
            .mobile{ width:300px; display:block; padding: 0 !important; text-align:center; }
            .mobile50{ width:300px; padding: 0 !important; text-align:center; }
            *[class="mobileOff"] { width: 0px !important; display: none !important; }
            *[class*="mobileOn"] { display: block !important; max-height: none !important; }
            table, td{width:320px !important; text-align:center !important; margin:0px auto;}
        }
    
    </style>
    
    <!--[if gte mso 15]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { font-size:1px; line-height:0; mso-margin-top-alt:1px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
        * { mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->    

</head>


<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" yahoo="fix" style="background-color:#F2F2F2; font-family:Arial,serif;margin:0;padding:0;min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;">

    <!-- Start Background -->
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" valign="top" align="center">
      

            <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper smdWidth" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                              
                        <!-- Start Container  -->
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container smdWidth">
                            <tr>


                                <td width="550" class="mobile" style="font-size:12px; line-height:18px;">
                                    <img src="IMAGE SOURCE HERE" alt="">
                                </td>
                                
                                    
                                
                                <td width="50" class="mobile" style="font-size:12px; line-height:18px;">
                                    <a href="LINK HERE"><img src="IMAGE SOURCE HERE" alt=""></a>
                                </td>
                                
                                <td width="50" class="mobile" style="font-size:12px; line-height:18px;">
                                    <a href="LINK HERE"><img src="IMAGE SOURCE HERE" alt=""></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- Start Container  -->                   
                              
                    </td>
                </tr>
                     
            </table> 
            <!-- End Wrapper  --> 


            <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper smdWidth" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" >

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                              
                        <!-- Start Container  -->
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container smdWidth">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="600" height="199" class="mobile smdWidth" style="font-size:12px; line-height:18px;">
                                    <img style="width:100%; height:199px; display:block;" class="smdBanner" src="IMAGE SOURCE HERE" alt="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- Start Container  -->                   
                              
                    </td>
                </tr>
                        
            </table> 
            <!-- End Wrapper  -->            
            
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Background -->
    
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried setting hard heights to the table (TD), I've tried setting heights via css inline, ... nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling its the line height thats causing the issue. I have removed it from your code and its below. Let me know if it worked for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>TITLE HERE</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">

        table td {border: 0px solid #DDDDDD;} 

        .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; background-color: #F1F1F1; }
        .ExternalClass { width: 100%; background-color: #F1F1F1; }
        body { width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-family: Arial, Times, serif }
        *[class*="mobileOn"] { display: none !important; max-height: none !important; }

        @-ms-viewport{ width: device-width; }




        .smdWidth{width:600px;}
        .smdPadding{padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;}

        @media only screen and (max-width: 639px){
            .wrapper{ width:100%;  padding: 0 !important; }
        }    


        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){ 
            p{padding:10px;}
            .wrapper, .smdWidth{ width:320px;  padding: 0 !important; } 
            .centerClass{ margin:0 auto !important; } 
            .imgClass{width:100% !important; height:auto;}        
            .container{ width:300px;  padding: 0 !important; }
            .mobile{ width:300px; display:block; padding: 0 !important; text-align:center; }
            .mobile50{ width:300px; padding: 0 !important; text-align:center; }
            *[class="mobileOff"] { width: 0px !important; display: none !important; }
            *[class*="mobileOn"] { display: block !important; max-height: none !important; }
            table, td{width:320px !important; text-align:center !important; margin:0px auto;}
        }

    </style>

    <!--[if gte mso 15]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { font-size:1px; mso-margin-top-alt:1px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
        * { mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->    

</head>


<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" yahoo="fix" style="background-color:#F2F2F2; font-family:Arial,serif;margin:0;padding:0;min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;">

    <!-- Start Background -->
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" valign="top" align="center">


            <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper smdWidth" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">

                        <!-- Start Container  -->
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container smdWidth">
                            <tr>


                                <td width="550" class="mobile" style="font-size:12px;">
                                    <img src="IMAGE SOURCE HERE" alt="">
                                </td>



                                <td width="50" class="mobile" style="font-size:12px;">
                                    <a href="LINK HERE"><img src="IMAGE SOURCE HERE" alt=""></a>
                                </td>

                                <td width="50" class="mobile" style="font-size:12px;">
                                    <a href="LINK HERE"><img src="IMAGE SOURCE HERE" alt=""></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- Start Container  -->                   

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table> 
            <!-- End Wrapper  --> 


            <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper smdWidth" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" >

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">

                        <!-- Start Container  -->
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container smdWidth">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="600" height="199" class="mobile smdWidth" style="font-size:12px;">
                                    <img style="width:100%; height:199px; display:block;" class="smdBanner" src="IMAGE SOURCE HERE" alt="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- Start Container  -->                   

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table> 
            <!-- End Wrapper  -->            

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Background -->

</body>
</html>
```